# What do you call the country out of which someone has emigrated?

Tags: single-word-requests

Emigrant = someone who is leaving their country.

??? = the country from which the emigrant is departing.

I want to say Émigré country but I don't know if that makes sense.

Maybe country of emigration? But that's too wordy.

Is there *one word*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Native country](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/native-country)
*the country someone is born in or native to*

> Born Carmela Drelano, in Spain, it was very many years since she had
>   lived in her native country.

[Native land](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/native%20land)

> When I think of my own native land, In a moment I seem to be there; 
>   But alas! recollection at hand Soon hurries me back to despair

[Native soil](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/native_soil)
*The country or geographical region where one was born or which one considers to be one's true homeland*

> Nawaz Sharif, two-time Prime Minister of Pakistan, had planned a
>   triumphant return to his native soil nearly seven years after choosing
>   exile.

If the OP wishes a similar one word expression still connected to *native*, then I suggest
[birthplace](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/birthplace?&o=100074&s=t)

> - He knows what spot this is: the birthplace  of their country.
> - At the age of 27, Arriaga **emigrated from his birthplace**, the port of
>     Callao, Peru, to Canada. <sub>[source](http://marcosarriaga.com/promised-land/)</sub>
> - [Pulitzer](http://www.stlmediahistory.com/index.php/Print/PrintHOFDetail/pulitzer-joseph) emigrated from **his birthplace in Hungary** to New York in 1864 when he was 17.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "[**country of origin**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immigration_to_the_United_States)."

Answer (score 2):

I think **home country** reflects well the idea of what you left by emigrating.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your audience. A speech would be different than a novel.

In nonfiction writing or speech, "country of origin" is the most respectful and politically-sensitive way of phrasing this.

"Home country" doesn't work if the person has neither a home nor feels at home there.

"Native country" also doesn't work because it may not be where someone is native from.  Consider a refugee of palestine who has emigrated from Egypt. While their native country may be Palestine/Israel, if they sought temporary political asylum in Egypt, and then emigrated to England, their country of origin would be Egypt.

In fiction and informal writing, "homeland."

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, it would be **homeland** or **motherland**.

But "**[old country](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20country)**" is used also

> an emigrant's country of origin

---

Additionally, **"source country"** is used in immigration related or technical sources